# How to find regularity, the signed curvature, and arc length of $\gamma(s)+\epsilon \pmb{n}(s)$

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

**Question:** Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a regular plane curve. For a constant $\epsilon\in \mathbb{R}$, define $\tilde{\gamma}:s\mapsto \gamma(s)+\epsilon \pmb{n}(s)$. Show that

i) If $|\epsilon|\ll 1$, then $\tilde{\gamma}$ is regular.

ii) What is the new curve's arc length and signed curvature in terms of $\gamma$'s.

**What did I do:** We want to show that $|\tilde{\gamma}'(s)|\neq 0$, therefore, $$|\gamma'+\epsilon\pmb{n}'|=\left\lvert|\gamma'|\pmb{t}+\epsilon(-|\gamma'|\kappa\pmb{t}+|\gamma'|\tau\pmb{b})\right\rvert\neq 0\iff \pmb{t}+\epsilon(-\kappa\pmb{t}+\tau\pmb{b})\neq 0$$ However, I could not continue because I am not sure how to use $\kappa$ and $\tau$ after that. How should I continue or should I change my starting point?

I search some question in here and I think most of the people use the notation $T(s)$ and $N(s)$ instead of $\pmb{t}(s)$ and $\pmb{n}(s)$. Also, $\pmb{b}(s)$ is the unit binormal which is equal to $\pmb{t}(s)\times \pmb{n}(s)$.

Comment: I will denote the derivative with respect to $s$ as $'$. $s$ is the natural parameter of $\gamma$.

$$
\bar{\gamma}' = \gamma' + \epsilon \mathbb{n}'
= \mathbb{t} + \epsilon ( -k(s) \mathbb{t} + \tau(s) \mathbb{b})
= (1-\epsilon k(s))\mathbb{t}+\tau(s) \mathbb{b}
$$
Since $k:[a,b] \rightarrow (0,+\infty)$ is a continuous function on a compact interval, it has a maximal value $K_M$. Choose $\epsilon < 1/k_M$ and you can then prove that $(1-\epsilon k(s))\neq 0$ for all $s\in [a,b]$. Sine $\{t,n,b\}$ is an orthonormal basis you get $\bar{\gamma}'\neq 0$ from that.

Comment: @topolosaurus What if $K_M<1$? In this case, we know there exists some $\epsilon<\frac{1}{K_M}<1$ makes $\tilde{\gamma}$ regular but is it enough? I think I am not sure what "$\ll$" means.

Comment: I interpret $|\epsilon|<<1$ as "there exists some epsilon sufficiently small such that $\bar{\gamma}$ is regular"- If the maximal value is $k_M < 1$ then any $|\epsilon|$ between 0 and 1 will do, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the signed curvature of $\gamma$ at $s$ is
$$
   k_\gamma(s)= \langle N'_\gamma(s), T_\gamma(s)\rangle,
$$
where $T_\gamma(s) = \gamma'(s)/\Vert\gamma'(s)\Vert$ and $N_\gamma(s)\perp T_\gamma(s)$. Therefore, given $\epsilon\in\mathbb R$, we have
$$
  (\gamma(s) + \epsilon N_\gamma(s))'
    = \gamma'(s) - \epsilon k_\gamma(s) T_\gamma(s)
    = (\Vert\gamma'(s)\Vert - \epsilon k_\gamma(s))T_\gamma(s).
$$
Now, observing that $[a,b]$ is compact, and $\gamma'(s)\ne0$, we deduce that the maximum
$$
  c=\max\Big\{\frac{|k_\gamma(s)|}{\Vert\gamma'(s)\Vert}\mid s\in[a,b]\Big\}
$$
is attained in $[a,b]$. In particular, $\bar\gamma$ is regular for $0<\epsilon < 1/(c+1)$ because in this case $\Vert\gamma'(s)\Vert>\epsilon k_\gamma(s)$.

To find the arc-length of $\bar\gamma$ observe that, by definition, it equals
$$
   \ell(\bar\gamma) = \int_a^b\Vert\bar\gamma'(s)\Vert\,ds
      = \int_a^b(\Vert\gamma'(s)\Vert-\epsilon k_\gamma(s))\,ds
      = \ell(\gamma)-\epsilon\int_a^bk_\gamma(s)\,ds.
$$